# How to use "bucketed_by" in AWS Glue job?

Tags: aws-glue

Can you please help me with the following issue? I want to use "bucketed_by" in the following code below:
`

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"withHeader": True, "separator": ",", "optimizePerformance": False},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://source-files-1029/sample_file.csv"]},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=S3bucket_node1,
    mappings=[
        ("client_id", "string", "client_id", "string"),
        ("product_id", "string", "product_id", "string"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.getSink(
    path="s3://destination-files-1029/glue-partition-bucket/",
    connection_type="s3",
    updateBehavior="LOG",
    partitionKeys=["client_id"],
    compression="snappy",
    enableUpdateCatalog=True,
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)
S3bucket_node3.setCatalogInfo(
    catalogDatabase="db1029", catalogTableName="tbl-partition-bucket"
)
S3bucket_node3.setFormat("glueparquet")
S3bucket_node3.writeFrame(ApplyMapping_node2)
job.commit()
```

`

Thank you.

I tried some code from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html#ctas-example-bucketed, but did not helped.

I used CTAS in Athena as additional step and I got the results as I wanted: partitioned and bucketed by the count of the bucket that I set in each partition folder.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing / where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to achieve the following: partitioning will stay the same and in this partitioning folders I want to split the partition file from one to 10. So, I will have for example 75 partition folders with 750 files inside (10 in each partition folder).